# How to run encodeURIComponent with one exception?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple statement in javascript.

`encodeURIComponent( "/nodes/client&123" );`

I want it to exclude the slash sign `/` from encoding. Is there a better way to do it than this

`encodeURIComponent( data.message.dav_uri ).replace("%2F","/");`

Answer (score 1):

The `encodeURI()` function will do what you want. The `encodeURIComponent()` function is for what its name implies: *pieces* of a URI, like parameter names and values.

It's safer to use `encodeURIComponent()` on the query string portion of a URI that your code constructs, using it separately for each parameter name and parameter value.

Comment: But that wouldn't encode the & sign. I want that every other sign except / sign be encoded

Comment: @rexroxm then you have to build the URI piece by piece, or else write your own method. Those functions do what they do, and there are no options to change the behavior.